# copy all files from one folder to a destination in matlab

Tags: matlab, filepath

I have a folder (says ORIG) containing many subfolders (each subfolder also contain its subfolders and so on). I am trying to copy all files with extention *.fig to a new folder (DEST) with exact the same subfolder structures. Since there is too much subfolders, it takes too long to create those subfolders manually. So I am looking for a way to do it with program. I find a code called dirr to list all the files recursively and I am trying to write the simply code to retrieve all *.fig files as follow

```
clear all;
clc;

oldpath = 'd:\myfig';
newpath = 'c:\matlabdata\plotting\figs';
[files, bytes, names] = dirr([oldpath ], 'name');
oldfullpaths = names(:);
newfullpaths = strrep(oldfullpaths, oldpath , newpath );

copyfile(oldfullpaths, newfullpaths)
```

This code doesn't work because the newfullpaths contains some paths which are not exist. Is that any way to copy the file from one place to a destination and if the destination folder doesn't exist create it first.

Comment: From the docs to `copyfile()`: [Copy Files to a New, Nonexistent Folder](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/copyfile.html#btm0bv4-4) which works automatically. What is the error message you get?

Comment: Thanks for reply. But copyfile doesn't work here. It errors out 'cannot file the path'. I run a simply test copyfile('c:\abc\a.fig', 'd:\efg\a.fig'); d:\efg doesn't exist and copyfile terminates with error. But if I create d:\efg manually ahead, no error.

Comment: What if you try: `copyfile('c:\abc\a.fig', 'd:\efg\')`. If it doesn't work it might help to know which MATLAB version you have.

Comment: It doesn't work either. I am running MATLAB R2013a

Comment: Can you please post the full error message?

Comment: the error message is "Error using copyfile:" and the description of the error is in my native language means "The system cannot find the path"

Answer (score 1):

I finally find one way to do so. I first list all the files, enumerate each of the file, extract the path, replace the oldpath to new one, if the new path doesn't exist, mkdir it first then copy the old file to the new one one at a time. It is not fast but at least work. Please let me know if anyone have better idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a shell escape:

```
!cp -r [old dir] [new dir]
```

Where `[old dir]` is the path to the old folder and `[new dir]` is the path to the new folder that either exists or will be created.

**EDIT**: On Windows, you may be able to use the `dos` command as:

```
dos('copy [old dir] [new dir]')
```

I am unable to test this, sorry.

Comment: Does that work on Windows? The asker seems to be using either Windows or Linux.

Comment: Ah, that is a good question and one which I am unable to test. Sorry. You might try the `dos` command [documentation here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dos.html).

Comment: thanks all, above doesn't work on my case. For testing, I am using windows but I might need to run it on another machine which have linux installed too.

Answer (score 0):

In MATLAB R2017a you can use the [`copyfile`](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/copyfile.html) function as follows:

```
copyfile('path for source\*', 'path for destination\');
```